# How can I turn a string into multiple sub arrays in Javascript?

Tags: arrays, string, object

I would like to turn this:

```
"a:1,b:2,c:3"
```

Into:

```
  [['a', '1'],['b', '2'],['c', '3']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same idea, but a little cooler ;)

```js
let str = "a:1,b:2,c:3";
let result = str.split(',').map(x=>x.split(":"))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JavaScript split method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and do it twice.
Something like the following:

```js
let array = [];
let str = "a:1,b:2,c:3";
let splitStr = str.split(',');
splitStr.forEach(subStr => {
    array.push(subStr.split(':'));
});
console.log(array);
```